# CronJob on windows machine in Python Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cron

I have setup job as below:

In **settings.py**:

```
CRON_CLASSES = [
    "kiteconnect_source.source.cron.MyCronJob",
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *','kiteconnect_source.source.cron.MyCronJob')
]
```

In **Cron job python file**:

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule
import datetime

class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    ALLOW_PARALLEL_RUNS = False
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1

schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
code = 'kiteconnect_source.my_cron_job'    # a unique code

def do(self):
    # time = datetime.datetime.now()
    val = "This is cron job function new testing:"
    f = open('/dummy.txt','a')
    f.write(val)
    f.close()
    print("demo")
```

Issue is it's getting executed only once instead of every interval of one minute.

Can anyone explain what I've missed? Thanks.

Comment: Can you check the indentation in the class?

Comment: @WBM it doesn't give any error.

Comment: Looks ok now, @Timus edited it